# How do I split one file into two files using Python?

Tags: python, file, split

I have a file containing some lines of code followed by a string pattern. I need to write everything before the line containing the string pattern in file one and everything after the string pattern in file two:

e.g. (file-content)

- codeline 1
- codeline 2
- string pattern
- codeline 3

The output should be file one with codeline 1, codeline 2 and file two with codeline 3.

I am familiar with writing files, but unfortunately I do not know how to determine the content before and after the string pattern.

Comment: Could you give an example of the string pattern and codeline used? - Also is it a .csv file or just a regular .txt file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the input file fits into memory, the easiest solution is to use `str.partition()`:

```
with open("inputfile") as f:
    contents1, sentinel, contents2 = f.read().partition("Sentinel text\n")
with open("outputfile1", "w") as f:
    f.write(contents1)
with open("outputfile2", "w") as f:
    f.write(contents2)
```

This assumes that you know the exact text of the line separating the two parts.

Comment: +1. This is a really nice, clean, readable solution if it fits in memory.

Comment: +1 my favorite, prefer it over my own solution if given the same caveat regarding fitting in memory

Answer (score 5):

This approach is similar to [Lev's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11021025/344821) but uses `itertools` because it's fun.

```
 dont_break = lambda l: l.strip() != 'string_pattern'

 with open('input') as source:
     with open('out_1', 'w') as out1:
         out1.writelines(itertools.takewhile(dont_break, source))
     with open('out_2', 'w') as out2:
         out2.writelines(source)
```

You could replace the dont_break function with a regular expression or anything else if necessary.

Comment: This is probably the best solution for files that won't fit in memory. Itertools means the loops are done C-side which means they'll be faster (which could matter given the large number of lines one would expect where memory matters) I'd note that if you are going to define a lambda separately like that, you might as well use a `def` statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('data.txt') as inf, open('out1.txt','w') as of1, open('out2.txt','w') as of2:
    outf = of1
    for line in inf:
        if 'string pattern' in line:
            outf = of2
            continue  # prevent output of the line with "string pattern" 
        outf.write(line)
```

will work with large files since it works line by line. Assumes `string pattern` occurs only once in the input file. I like the `str.partition()` approach best *if* the whole file can fit into memory (which may not be a problem)

Using `with` ensures the files are automatically closed when you are done, or an exception is encountered.

Comment: Close, but I believe your code will result in 'string pattern' appearing in `outf2`, when the question stated that 'string pattern' should disappear from the output. In that case, just add `continue` as the next line after `outf = outf2` and it should work.

Comment: @Robru I mentioned the use of `continue` to make the `string pattern` disappear , but I guess I should have read the question more carefully :-) .. I'll update my solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A naive example (that doesn't load the file into memory like Sven's):

```
with open('file', 'r') as r:
    with open('file1', 'w') as f:
        for line in r:
            if line == 'string pattern\n':
                break
            f.write(line)
    with open('file2', 'w') as f:
        for line in r:
            f.write(line)
```

This assumes that `'string pattern'` occurs once in the input file.

If the pattern isn't a fixed string, you can use the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module.

Comment: Use the `with` statement where opening files.

Comment: @Lattyware this is a _naive_ example :) Also, in this particular case it's more complicated than usual to adapt the code to using `with`.

Comment: And? `with` is the best practice. There is no reason not to use it. The idea that it's hard to change simply isn't true - with is easier to use and ensures files are closed, even on exceptions - something your code doesn't even attempt at the moment.

Comment: @Lattyware I know it's the best practice, thank you. I think we all get that now. I don't want to use it in this answer, okay? Feel free to downvote. Or edit. I was sure there'd be enough answers using `with` for the OP to see this is common practice. I came up with this and decided to post it. After all, considering the OP hasn't shown a single line of code, I figured that it would be better not try for the complete and absolute solution. This is not `tehcodezoverflow`, remember?

Comment: You seem to have taken offence, if you know it's the best idea, then why not use it? If you don't want to give code without seeing code, ask for code from the asker, don't give an answer which works but has hidden potential bugs - that's harmful to everyone (such as people who might come across this question looking for an answer later). I am giving a suggestion to improve the answer, which is in line with the way SO is meant to work. That's not an attack on you, it's an attempt to improve the resource.

Comment: @Lattyware I'm not the only one to see the comments on my posts, right? Anyone reading the answer will see your comment. One is enough, really. The OP said he knew how to handle files, after all.

Comment: Comments don't display it clearly enough. In the spirit of SO, I made the edit myself (and fixed another subtle bug - the pattern needs a newline to work).

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient answer which will handle large files and consume a limited amount of memory..

```
inp = open('inputfile')
out = open('outfile1', 'w')
for line in inp:
  if line == "Sentinel text\n":
    out.close()
    out = open('outfile2', 'w')
  else:
    out.write(line)
out.close()
inp.close()
```

Comment: Use the `with` statement where opening files.

Answer (score 2):

No more than three lines:

```
with open('infile') as fp, open('of1','w') as of1, open('of2','w') as of2:
    of1.writelines(iter(fp.readline, sentinel))
    of2.writelines(fp)
```

Comment: Good point! I always forget about that form of `iter`. Of course, it only works for exact known sentinels, not regex matches or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like:

```
def test_pattern(x):
    if x.startswith('abc'): # replace this with some exact test
        return True
    return False

found = False
out = open('outfile1', 'w')
for line in open('inputfile'):
    if not found and test_pattern(line):
        found = True
        out.close()
        out = open('outfile2', 'w')
    out.write(line)
out.close()
```

replace the line with startswith with a test that works on your pattern (using pattern matching from re if necessary, but anything that finds the devider line will do).

Comment: This will result in a `NameError` for `true` or `false`.  Simply use `return x.startswith('abc')` instead of the `if` statement.

Comment: Use the `with` statement where opening files.

Comment: @Sven: thanks for noticing the typos. IMHO a oneliner is inappropriate if you do not know exactly how to test yet, this was just an easily expandable example with fallthrough on being False. If the test becomes multiline with other if statements, e.g. look for first 2 characters, then split on '|' and inspect the following two characters, then this is more easily adaptable.

Comment: @Lattyware: with is nice but inappropriate as it is a relatively new addition to Python and we don't know which version of Python dom_frank is using.

Comment: @Anthon Nobody who's just learning python is going to use anything pre-2.5; if the OP is using 2.5, then he just needs to add `from __future__ import with_statement`.

Comment: @Anthon Just because something is new doesn't mean it should be avoided, besides that, as Dougal says, this is not by any means a new feature. It's standard and everyone (as they should) uses it. I consider any new code not using it as wrong - it introduces potential bugs for no reason and lowers readability.